# struct - might not be initialized before use

Tags: c#, struct

Given the follow contrived struct

```
public struct CarParts
{
        public int trunk;
        public int door;
}
```

Why do I get an error that says "cp might not be initialized before use" however if I do the exact same thing in a static method id doesnt work. Also why did it used to comple before I added the static method?

```
public void Test()
{
            CarParts cp;
            cp.trunk= 1;
            cp.door= 4;
}
```

Comment: Did I guess the language correctly? You really should tag with what language you're using whenever you want to discuss your actual code.

Comment: Please show the code which is failing. The code you've posted does not fail on its own.

Comment: Note 1: You can't assign to properties(even auto-properties) before initializing all fields. Note 2: mutable structs are evil. Note 3: public instance fields are usually bad style

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that this is relevant to your question:

> When you create a struct object using the new operator, it gets created and the appropriate constructor is called. Unlike classes, structs can be instantiated without using the new operator. If you do not use new, the fields will remain unassigned and the object cannot be used until all of the fields are initialized.

Comment: That was the issue one of the fields was not being set before returning I had added another field to the struct. Thanks!!